# Comparing IF statements to a final script with outcome

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def coordinates():

    coordinate_X = int
    coordinate_Y = int

    userx = int(input("Please enter a number for coordinate x"))
    usery = int(input("coordinate y"))
    accepted = (True) or (False)
    accepted2 = (True) or (False)

    accepted = False
    if userx range(0, 600):
        return print("error")
    else accepted = True:
        return print("ook")

    accepted2 = False
    if usery range(0, 400):
    return print("error") 
        return print("error")
    else accepted2 = True:
        return print("ok")

    if accepted + accepted2 = True:
        return print("coordinates are ok")
    else:
        return print("coordinates are not ok")


coordinates()
```

What I want to happen is that, if the top two if-statements are `True` (they evaluate `userx` and `usery`), then the bottom if-statement will return a different answer.

Comment: `=` does assignment, not equality testing. you can't assign `true` to the result of a mathemtical expression. don't do "math" with booleans. why not just `if (accepted && accepted2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def coordinates():
    userx = int(input("Please enter a number for coordinate x"))
    usery = int(input("coordinate y"))

    accepted = False
    if userx in range(0, 600):
        print("invalid x coordinate")
    else:
        accepted = True
        print("ok")

    accepted2 = False
    if usery in range(0, 400):
        print("invalid y coordinate")
    else:
        accepted2 = True
        print("ok")

    if accepted and accepted2:
        print("coordinates are ok")
    else:
        print("coordinates are not ok")

coordinates()
```

Something like this?

Comment: Correct. But I had to change  if accepted and accepted2: to  if accepted & accepted2:

Answer (score 1):

First off, `accepted = (True) or (False)` will simply evaluate to `accepted = True` because of boolean logic. Instead, initialize both accepted and accepted2 as `= False` initially.

Next, `if accepted + accepted2 = True:`, you are missing one `=` sign, as `=` is for assignment, and `==` is for comparison.

For boolean logic, `accepted + accepted2` is equivalent to `accepted or accepted2`, meaning that if either is `True` the result will be `True`. If you want to check that both are `True`, use `accepted and accepted2` instead.

So you'd want `if accepted and accepted2 == True:` as your if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this: You should use `=` to assign value to a variable. Use `==` if you want to compare. Read  [this](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html) for if-else statement familiartization.

```
def coordinates():

    userx = int(input("Please enter a number for coordinate x"))
    usery = int(input("coordinate y"))
    accepted = False
    accepted2 = False


    if userx in range(0, 600):
       print("invalid x coordinate")
    else:
      accepted = True
      print("ok")

    if usery in range(0, 400):
      print("invalid y coordinate")
    else:
      accepted2 = True
      print("ok")

    if accepted and accepted2:
      print("coordinates are ok")
    else:
      print("coordinates are not ok")


coordinates()
```

Comment: I think op is using python 3.  @JoshuaSnider

Comment: This also throws a syntax error with Python 3.4.3. `if userx range(0, 600) ` should probably be `if userx in range(0, 600)`. You also return immediately regardless of input.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider This moves it onto the final if statement but it responds with the wrong answer

Comment: @FraserVigrass: Are valid coordinates within 0-400 and 0-600 or outside of them?

Comment: @JoshuaSnider inside them is the True statement. I changed the else to False but this should be ok I assume